# Show $m^*((A-y) \cap E+y) = m^*((A-y) \cap E)$.

Tags: real-analysis, outer-measure

[image]

I don't understand how $$m^*((A-y) \cap E+y) = m^*((A-y) \cap E)$$.

Would someone explain?

Comment: I think the first equality is a typo. The second one came from the fact $m^*(A)=m^*(A-y)$ the outer measure is translation invariant

Comment: @AmerYR What's the first equality?

Comment: $m(A \cup (E+y))=m((A-y) \cup E+y)$ it should be$m(A \cup (E+y))=m((A-y) \cup E)$